# How to sum VBA values based on conditions?

Tags: vba, sum, conditional-statements

I have the following setup:

```
C1  C2  
10  EUR 
20  GBP
40  EUR
60  USD
```

How can I iterate over these cells and sum up all EUR and all other currencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that in column A you have the amount and column B the currency; and start from row 1:

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SumEUR As Long, SumOtherCurrency As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws

For i = 1 To .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If .Cells(i, "B") = "EUR" Then
        SumEUR = SumEUR + .Cells(i, "A")
    Else
        SumOtherCurrency = SumOtherCurrency + .Cells(i, "A")
    End If

Next i

End With

MsgBox ("SUM EUR :" & SumEUR & vbNewLine & "Sum Other :" & SumOtherCurrency)

End Sub
```